# lxc, how to control which interface lxcbr0 is defined on?

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

We have a host with production and management networks.

Using the default setup, containers use lxcbr0. However, we cant find where this 
interface is defined, or which of our networks (management o production) it is using.  We also want to change it to configure the dns server etc.

We know that in theory, you can setup your own bridge in /etc/network/interfaces, but this is not an option for us as for some unknown reason, when we define a simple bridge on any of our bonded interfaces, networking wont start (and there is no solution).

So our only option is to figure out how to manipulate lxcbr0 to do what we want.

Just to be clear, the host has 2 physical interfaces bonded for failover between two switches, and eache of these has 2 vlans for prod and managmenet networks. We need to know:

1. how to find out which of these many interfaces lxcbr0 is actually bridging to
2. how to change it to use a different one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

## UPDATE

The reason I could not find the interface definition anywhere is that it is not defined as a bridge, it appears to be implemented using iptables forwarding rules.  The default rules setup do not care about the incoming network or source.  The iptables are setup in /etc/init/lxc-net.conf.  So I guess the way to change this would be to edit this file (as bridging a bonded pair of interfaces in /etc/network/interfaces does not work).

The rules created are thus:

```
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

I our case, the first 4 rules do nothing as all packets are accepted by default.  Apparently, 53 and 67 are domain and bootps (for DNS)

could anyone explain what the two forward rules do exactly?

Ubuntu 14

Answer (score 1):

check...

/etc/lxc/default.conf

Also, flockport has a lot of good information which you might find useful.

https://www.flockport.com/guides/

Comment: Thanks bmullan.  Found a guide from you link: https://www.flockport.com/lxc-networking-guide/ which says the bridge is defined in /etc/init/lxc-net.conf, but I cant see in this file which physical interfaces lxc uses in its defaul NAT bridge, nor how to change it.